# Disable web middleware per Route::group

Tags: laravel, routes, middleware

In Laravel 5.2 the web middleware is included on all routes by default. However, I would like to disable this middleware for all routes within my Api route group without having to specify in each controller to ignore the web middleware.

I do not wish to remove the middleware all together as this is a hybrid app serving both types of clients and still require the xsrf-checking. Is there a way to ignore or 'except' middleware per route group?

Answer (score 3):

Since Laravel 7.7 you can use `excluded_middleware` property eg:

```php
Route::group([
    'prefix' => 'forgot-password',
    'excluded_middleware' => ['auth'],
], function () {
    Route::post('send-email', 'ForgotPasswordController@sendEmail');
    Route::post('save-new-password', 'ForgotPasswordController@saveNewPassword');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

#### My Approach

You may separate you `routes` file in another file. Check `RouteServiceProvider` class. In `map` method, add another line:

```
public function map(Router $router)
{
    $this->mapWebRoutes($router);

    // This method will register your routes which doesn't need 'web' middleware 
    $this->mapNoMiddlewareRoutes($router);
}
```

Then add `mapNoMiddlewareRoutes` method:

```
protected function mapNoMiddlewareRoutes(Router $router)
{
    $router->group([
        'namespace' => $this->namespace,
    ], function ($router) {
        require app_path('Http/no_middleware_routes.php');
    });
}
```

}

Finally, add `no_middleware_routes.php` file within `app/Http` folder.

```
Route::get('/foo', function () {
    return ['foo' => 'bar'];
});
```

#### 2nd Approach

Based on [this](https://laravel-news.com/2015/06/excluding-routes-from-the-csrf-middleware/) article, you can use `except` attribute.

```
// app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php

protected $except = [
    'webhook/*'
];
```

> As you can see from the example, you can utilize wildcards for route matching or define each one individually. Internally, this array is ran through $request->is and you can find more details about that in the requests documentation.

Read more at [CSRF Protection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#csrf-protection) documentation

Comment: This looks like it would work...I will try this for now, but may look into overriding the route middleware loader to provide an 'except' method which I assumed would already be in there considering it exists in the controller middleware stuff.

Comment: See this https://laravel-news.com/2015/06/excluding-routes-from-the-csrf-middleware/